# While Loop does not stop when condition is false

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, loop

Here's the code:

```
void loop() {
  while (1 == 1) {
    ObsLeft();
    while (SeeLeft < 50 || SeeLeft == 50) {
      Urong();
      ObsLeft();
      if (SeeLeft > 50) {
        Hinto;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`ObsLeft()` analogReads the Infrared sensor input and Serial.prints it

`Urong()` makes the sumobot go backward

`Hinto()` stops the robot

`SeeLeft` is the analog value given by the Line Sensor (in my experience, white is 42, black is 800+)

The Problem:

When I run the program with the sensor seeing White, it makes the robot go backward, but when I move the bot so that the sensor sees Black, it still keeps going.

When I run the program with the sensor seeing Black, it does nothing.

Comment: `while (1==1)` is redundant. the `loop()` loops

Comment: `Hinto;` is the address of the function. `Hinto();` calls the function.

Comment: Please post a full functioning code. Also I think you have forgotten the parenthesizes after `Hinto`, since it is a function. Maybe a copy paste error. Is 50 really a good value to distinguish between black and white, when white is 42 and black is over 800? In such a situation the analog value might easily go over 50 due to noise. Have you tried a threshold value a bit higher, maybe 100?

Comment: `while (SeeLeft < 50 || SeeLeft == 50) {` is same as `while (SeeLeft <= 50) {`

Comment: Usually, in arduino programming `while` loops should rather be `if`statements and leave looping to the loop() function. This is a good example. As long as there's no definition of variables (SEELEFT) and no hint where, why and how they ever change, any more help is questionable.

Comment: have you considered the possibility that the condition is not false?